# React variable formatted date

Tags: reactjs

How can I format a date variable with React JSX 
I want to add code to diplay the variable below in a format like '27 June 2019'

```
<p>{publishedAt}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for that

```
import moment from 'moment'

/**
   Your Code
**/
<p>{moment(publishedAt).format("DD MMMM YYYY")}</p>
```

Comment: Great thanks. I didnt realise that moment was necessary for this

Comment: you can also do this manually in raw javascript, but `moment.js` will save you time.